# Cumulocity SCADA Widget - Can I use a value calculated/transformated from a measurement on a SCADA widget?

Tags: svg, widget, cumulocity, scada

Can I use a value calculated/transformated from a measurement on a SCADA widget of Cumulocity? I mean, I need to convert a temperature measurement (from -20 to 100) to a value between (-90 to 90) for use it in a SVG graphics.

Thnks

Answer (score 2):

You can do the calculation inside your SVG file. Best approach is to "declare" your placeholders somewhere in the beginning in comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- {{freeAvailable}} -->
<!-- {{totalAvailable}} -->
...
```

and then at the place where you want to do your calculation you can just use angular expressions

```
<rect stroke="#00ff5c" x="{{(((totalAvailable - freeAvailable) / totalAvailable) * 400) + 50 | number : 0}}px" height="100px" y="150px" stroke-width="nonepx" width="{{((freeAvailable / totalAvailable) * 400) | number : 0}}px" id="rect3" fill="#00ff5c" transform="" />
```

Comment: It runs!!! I've tried this: {{var1}}*{{var2}} , but it's a fault. The solution, as you said, is include the operations in the angular tag {{var1*var2}}. Great!!